# Extending tsconfig.json file doesn't seem to extend anything

Tags: typescript, tsconfig

I have a project from which I need to build two different products. Say I have

```
./src/advanced
./src/basic
```

All code is written in Typescript so I need to compile this with `tsc`

Because of this, I created 3 **tsconfig** files

*tsconfig-base.json*

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "lib": ["es2018", "dom", "dom", "dom.iterable", "es6"],
    "importHelpers": true,
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/*.spec.ts","dist"]
```

Now to build the `basic` product I have

*tsconfig-basic.json*

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig-base.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noEmitHelpers": true
  },
  "files": [
     "basic/main.ts"
  ]
}
```

And I compile as follows

```
$> tsc -p ./tsconfig-basic.json
```

Now I have 2 issues

1) The file `basic/main.ts` cannot be found, its looking in `./basic/main.ts` while it should have been `./src/basic/main.ts`. Why is `baseUrl` not prepended?

2) If (1) is fixed, the compiled files are not written to `./dist`. Why is `"outDir": "./dist` from the base file not used here? When I add the `outDir` to *tsconfig-basic.json* it works as expected

Anyway, it looks like that extending here doesn't work, or works differently than I expect. Any suggestion how to improve my setup?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

1) `baseUrl` is only meant to be used with bundlers like webpack. See discussion on [TypeScript/10866](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10866)

2) This is unfortunately by design. See issue [TypeScript/29172](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29172)

> Quote Wesley Wigham (Microsoft Employee):
>   Path-based compiler options (outDir, outFile, rootDir, include, files) are resolved from the config file they're found in)

You will need to repeat the `outDir` for every `tsconfig.json` file you have.

Answer (score 8):

There is a trick though. If you create a symlink to the base Tsconfig file from a relevant directory and extend the symlinked version rather than the original, all the paths will be resolved according to your expectations.

Comment: Can you share an example of how to do this in code?